# Check if a function is running in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, function

If I have these two fuctions:

```
def func1():
    print "I am function1"

def func2():
    print "Function 1 is still running."

while(func1 is running):
    func2()
```

How do I check if function 1 is still running?

Comment: ... are these asynchronous? If they are serial, then they run in order...

Comment: Python is synchronous by default so when `func1` actually runs, it will block the main thread and not continue your program until the function is complete.

Comment: How can I run both at the same time, but stop func2 as long as func1 stops running?

Comment: Read about the `threading` module in the docs. It provides threads to run things in parallel and synchronization primitives to control the order of execution between threads.

Comment: Give us more details on your use case.  The threading module mentioned by Michael could be the answer.  Or you may need generators and coroutines. Or you may need two completely separate Python processes. Can you describe the situation further?

Comment: I used the thread module and found a function called isAlive() that checks if a thread is still running.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this using the threading module. Below is my code.

```
import threading
from threading import Thread

func1_thread = Thread(target = func1)

while func1_thread.isAlive():
    func2()
```